# Interesting combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There is $n*n$ square grid. How many ways to fill it with $1$ and $0$ do we have, in case the sum in every row and every column should be even.
The problem seems to be easy, but after some time and with effort, I didn't manage to solve it.
First I tried to find some kind of recurrence relation, but that approach didn't lead me to anything useful. Also attempted to think about rotating the grid and symmetry. Noticed that after permuting rows , permuting columns, if there was the even-sum property, it remains. This perhaps will be useful, in a full solution.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding Mark Bennett's answer: if we consider the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ subgrid, the number of rows with an odd number of $1$'s has the same parity of the number of columns with an odd number of $1$'s, since they both depend on the parity of the number of $1$'s on the subgrid. So, for *any* $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ subgrid, there is only one way to extend it to a $n\times n$ grid satisfying the given constraints: we have to add a $1$ in the last position of every row/column with and odd number of $1$'s, then adjust the bottom right corner accordingly. This gives that there are $2^{(n-1)^2}$ grids satisfying the given constraints.

Comment: *bump* The final step one should add is to verify that: any solution in the set given by choosing one $(n-1)$x$(n-1)$ submatrix of free variables is contained in the set given by choosing another such submatrix. Further note that this submatrix need not be connected and could be split into 4 rectangular matrices. This is simple to do.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider the top $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ square. What can you say about the other entries?